# Generate the number of "(x,y)" data in a cell with reference to a number

Tags: excel, vba

(eg: 1=(x1,y1), 3=(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)

How do i remove the unnecessary "(,)" as shown below and put the number of position of the x,y coordinates of the reliability fail with reference to the number under the header of reliability fails?
Eg: Reliability fail counts =2 in device WLR8~LW~VBD~MNW should give me the position of that fail counts at the same row as the device at columnX. Anyways please ignore the data under the V and W column in my pictures.

**Current output based on my code**
[image]

**What i really want**
[image]

Current issue 
[image]

Current issue2
[image]
where it should be
[image]

```
Dim output As Variant
Dim outputrow As Integer
output = ""
outputrow = 0
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Dim ia As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
lastrow2 = ws1.Range("U2:U" & ws1.Rows.Count).Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

If ws1.Range("U1") = "Reliability Fail" Then
 For ia = 2 To lastrow2
    If ws1.Cells(ia, "U").Value = 0 Then
    output = output & "(" & ws1.Cells(ia, "Y").Value & "," & ws1.Cells(ia, "Z").Value & "),"
    ElseIf output = "(,)," Then 'if there are no x and y values in Y and Z column stop showing "(,),"
    output = ""
    End If
    If ws1.Cells(ia, "U").Value > 0 Then
    ws1.Cells(ia, "U").Offset(0, 3).Value = Left(output, Len(output) - 1) 'extract the x and y values obtain in (x,y) format
                    'if there is "value" under reliability fails(column U), put the x y position at the same row as the "value" at column X
    End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: @braX i get the argument not optional error when i replace output="" with  output = Replace("(,),", "")

Comment: @braX it still doesn't work when i replace out="" with output = Replace(output, "(,),", "")

Comment: @braX I have uploaded the link to the data just in case you need it

Comment: That's what I get for watching tv at the same time - `output = Replace(output, ",(,)", "")`

Comment: @braX ah your suggestions work only after I remove the   ElseIf output = "(,)," Then ' condition as well

Comment: @braX sorry about that, anyways thanks

Comment: Now i left with the generating  number of “(x,y)” data in a cell with reference to a number portion

Comment: @braX Like for example if data under reliabiltity fail header is =1, it will give the latest position that is found (8,2) at column x. If reliabiltity fail header is =2, latest position found is (9,3) and (10,4) while it will ignore the previous position (8,2) found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using an inner loop so that extra brackets don't get added in the first place

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()


Dim output As Variant
Dim outputrow As Integer
Dim valueCount As Long, ib As Long
output = ""
outputrow = 0
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Dim ia As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
lastrow2 = ws1.Range("U2:U" & ws1.Rows.Count).Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

If ws1.Range("U1") = "Reliability Fail" Then

' Outer loop over all rows
 For ia = 2 To lastrow2
  valueCount = ws1.Cells(ia, "U").Value
  output = ""

  ' Inner loop to process repeated rows
  For ib = 1 To valueCount
    output = output & "(" & ws1.Cells(ia + ib - 1, "Y").Value & "," & ws1.Cells(ia + ib - 1, "Z").Value & ")"
    If ib < valueCount Then output = output & ","
   Next ib
   ws1.Cells(ia, "U").Offset(0, 3).Value = output
 Next ia
End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Here is the amended code in light of OP's later example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim output As Variant
Dim outputrow As Integer
Dim valueCount As Long, ib As Long, rowPointer As Long
output = ""
outputrow = 0
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Dim ia As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
lastrow2 = ws1.Range("U2:U" & ws1.Rows.Count).Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

If ws1.Range("U1") = "Reliability Fail" Then

rowPointer = 2
' Outer loop over all rows
 For ia = 2 To lastrow2
  valueCount = ws1.Cells(ia, "U").Value
  output = ""

  ' Inner loop to process repeated rows
  For ib = 1 To valueCount
    output = output & "(" & ws1.Cells(rowPointer, "Y").Value & "," & ws1.Cells(rowPointer, "Z").Value & ")"
    If ib < valueCount Then output = output & ","
    rowPointer = rowPointer + 1
  Next ib
  ws1.Cells(ia, "U").Offset(0, 3).Value = output
 Next ia
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: your code works really great if i test it by itself but once i incorparate it with my other codes, it doesn't show the value tho. Could it be i have not declare some variables in  your code or missing out something? Anyways thanks

Comment: i have posted a picture to let you see the current issue im facing..

Comment: If you're using option explicit (which is good practice), then you need to define the new variables that I've used Dim valueCount As Long, ib As Long - will include in my code

Comment: sorry to disturb, your code doesnt seems  to work as intended where the data under reliability fails header are at different rows as shown above(i have posted some pictures labelled as current issue 2) what should i do to rectify it?

Comment: OK, that changes my understanding of the question quite a bit, but it shouldn't be too difficult to keep track of the row with another variable

Answer (score 1):

First, strip out the extra blank pairs using this:

```
output = Replace(Range("X" & lRow), ",(,)", "")
```

You should then have it down to just the pairs you want.

Then split it based on `),` and append a `)` if it doesnt end in one. Here is an example you can use to incorporate it in your code:

```
Sub test()
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim vSplit As Variant
  Dim sResult As String
  Dim output as String

  For lRow = 2 To 3

    If Len(Range("X" & lRow)) > 0 And Val(0 & Range("U" & lRow)) > 0 Then

      output = Replace(Range("X" & lRow), ",(,)", "")  ' this strips out the extra empty pairs

      vSplit = Split(output, "),") ' this creates a string array, 1 item for each pair

      sResult = vSplit(Val(Range("U" & lRow)) - 1) ' this gets the one you want based on column U ( -1 because the Split array is 0 based)

      If Right$(sResult, 1) <> ")" Then sResult = sResult & ")" ' this adds a ")" if one is missing

      Debug.Print sResult ' debug code

      Range("X" & lRow) = sResult ' this adds the result to column X, replacing what was there

   End If

  Next

End Sub
```